# Securing SWFs, written in Actionscript 2 and 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, obfuscation, security

I have around 3000 SWF files, some are interactive which has lots of actionscripts and some are just animated lessons for mathematics. Currently, users have access to these files through a web interface (PHP). Even though access to these files are restricted for unregistered users, the registered users can still download the files by getting the swf link from the HTML source view.

I would like to achieve the following:

1) Securing ActionScripts both 2 and 3.

2) Prevent users from stealing our SWFs. (swf won't run if they download and execute on the local machine. but still they can decompile).

I'm aware of secureSWF from http://www.kindisoft.com which I've already tested. It works fine and best suit my needs. The problem is I've to convert all of my 3000+ swfs.

Apart from obfuscation, can anyone suggest me some best practices to secure our hard works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: relax! Who would want to reverse engineer 3000 SWFs?

Comment: lol! of course not! But we don't want our competitor to steal ours. Our recent projects were stolen by them. I confirmed this when I suspect and decompiled their SWF. I found our packages were being used by them. Lol! I found my comments in their source code also!!!

Comment: I don't think there is anything other than obfuscation to secure your hard works, apart from not publishing it.

Comment: You found your comments in their source code? So you released your sourcecode completely? If you are big enough to make money off this, you could always sue them for copyright infringement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya that's rite!
As Tom said, Obfuscation is the best available method now.

But my concern was, to obfuscate all 3000 over files will be a pain. So I came with something which will automate the process. I just wrote a small piece of VB.net application to do so. (more like a batch file). Have not finalized yet.